# How can I prove that the probability that exactly 2 people share the same birthday is more likely than everyone has a different day out of 20 people?

Tags: probability, problem-solving, birthday

I will be thankful if you can help me and show how to solve this.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Why don't you first search the birthday problem on this site or Wikipedia ?

Comment: I tried but the they all explaind the probability of at last 2 people not exactly 2.

Comment: It is not true for $20$, or even for $23$.  What have you tried?

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

You can't prove it because it isn't true.
However, if you want to compute the probability that out of $20$ people, *exactly* two share the same birthday,

- There are $\large\binom{20}2$ ways the pair can be chosen, and $365$ ways they can share a birthday (ignoring leap years)
- The remaining $18$ have $364.363.362.361...347$ ways of having distinct birthdays different from the pair
- There are $365^{20}$ ways of having unconstrained birthdays
- You will find the probability to be well below $0.5$

Can you now compute what the number of people should be there for your assertion to be true ?